# How can I use 2014 (782) version of localDB in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, localdb, sql-server-2014-express

I have SQL Server 2014 installed, and I am trying to connect to a 2014 database in Visual Studio. If I try to use (under the advanced button) `LocalDB\v11`, then the version number is wrong. When I try to use the `SQLEXPRESS` (default name) instance (with user instance turned on, otherwise it complains that a database with that name already exists) it will connect, but when I try to run the web service it errors "unable to launch ISS server". So neither option works.

How can I get Visual Studio to recognize the SQL Server 2014 localDB?

Answer (score 0):

I think `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` should work. That seems to be the name of the automatic LocalDB instance in SQL Server 2014 (and probably going forward as well).

Comment: That is not an option in the settings when creating the connection. I do however have that service on my system. when looking at sqllocaldb.exe

Answer (score 0):

like @Krzysztof Kozielczyk use (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
but in the server name with datasource for " ms sql server (sqlClient)". it worked for me in visual studio 2013 pro.

in details:
tools, connect database

1. choose the Datasource as" microsof sql server database(sqlcient) after click change button
2. enter in the server name box:
   (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB2
3. check attach a database file and enter in the box below that

   yourDatabaseFileFullFilespec
   like the picture shown[image: visual studio Add Connection]

and click Test connection. if that works, click OK.

Otherwise try use instance pipe name instead of "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"

how to get instance pipe name?
  In command prompt enter
    SqlLocalDB.exe start v11.0
    SqlLocalDB.exe info v11.0
the alternative is something I found on the web and I have not tested it out

for me, I only need to use (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

for those curious about my sql server config:
  Ms sql server 2014 express localdb
  Ms sql server 2012 express localdb
with all the assoicated mgmt objects, compiler service, scriptdom. only native client 2012 not 2014
  ms sql server datatool v 11 and 12 as well as 2013
  ms sql server data tools bulid utilites v 11 and 12
  ms sql server system clr types 2012 and 2014

I may not need all that to get server explorer to work with 2014 localdb but that's what I got to work on different projects